# Ion Inifinte Scroll not showing in an empty page

Tags: ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

I know that the whole purpose of ionInfiniteScroll is to load more items. Yet as I'm calling an api that takes some time to respond, I want to use ionInfiniteScroll in the top of the page before loading the first items... (then obviously use it in the original way). I like the way it functions and I don't wanna create a hole preloader when I already have what I need.

##### But

When the page is empty and no scrolling is possible, the ionInfiniteScroll doesn't work.
What can I do?

```html
<app-page>
<div class="py-2">
    <announcement-post *ngFor="let post of posts" [data]="post"
        (reacted)="onReacted(post.id, $event)" [user]="userinfo"></announcement-post>
    <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="loadMore" (ionInfinite)="onIonInfinite($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Please wait..." loadingSpinner="bubbles"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
    {{loadMore}} <!-- Outputs true -->
    
</div>
</app-page>
```

> Note no error is thrown

##### How it worked before

```
posts:any[] = [];
page:number = 1

ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get<any[]>("foobar.com").subscribe(res => this.posts = res);
}

onIonInfinite($event) {
   this.http.get<any[]>("foobar.com?page="+this.page).subscribe(res => { this.posts.push(...res); this.page++; $event.target.complete(); });
}
```

then after it loads I scroll down and it works. I deleted the ngOnInit so the api can be called from onIonInifinte

```
posts:any[] = [];
page:number = 0;

onIonInfinite($event) {
   this.http.get<any[]>("foobar.com?page="+this.page).subscribe(res => { this.posts.push(...res); this.page++; $event.target.complete(); });
}
```

Comment: For starters you could post some code of what you have tried so far. And then also show any errors which might be happening on console.log and network panel. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @E.Maggini done, and btw there's no error. I think it has something to do with the fact that an empty page is not scrollable